# How many interpretations does it have? Provide the first-order logic notation for each interpretation.

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the following sentence:
“Two politicians spied on someone from every city.”
How many interpretations does it have? Provide the first-order logic notation for each interpretation.

Comment: What is your idea? Can you describe the reason of the ambiguity?

Comment: I want the solution like this one.The sentence “Every child climbed a tree” has two potential interpretations that
we can disambiguate using the first-order logic notation. These are the interpretations:
∀x child(x) → ∃y tree(y) ∧ climb(x, y)
“for all x, if x is a child, then there is a y such that y is a tree, and x climbs y”
∃y tree(y) ∧ ∀x child(x) → climb(x, y)
“there is a y such that for all x, x is a child, and x climbs y”